# which visual studio 2012 sku has the command window

Tags: visual-studio, command-window

i just installed visual studio 2012 express for C++. It doesn't have the command window available (it doesn't show up on View->Other Windows->Command Window).

After searching a bit, it seems that the visual studio 2012 express doesnt have it.
I assume that ultimate visual studio 2012 has it, but does anyone know if the professional sku has it as well?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is only free Express version that is crippled. I have VS2008 Professional, and Command Window is there.

Comment: my 2012 Ultimate -- 2010 Premium -- 2008 Professional all have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in express
http://alinconstantin.blogspot.co.nz/2012/08/command-window-and-immediate-window-are.html

Professional has it.